# "data has contents that are not what they are reported to be" paperclip with ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, paperclip

I am using paperclip with ckeditor and I get this error when i click on "send it to the server" : "data has contents that are not what they are reported to be".

That's what "attachment_file.rb" and "picture.rb" look like:

```
class Ckeditor::AttachmentFile < Ckeditor::Asset
    has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :content => '575>', :thumb => '80x80#' },
       :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "/config/s3.yml", :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
       :url => ":s3_domain_url"

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_size :data, less_than: 100.megabytes
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :data

  def url_thumb
    @url_thumb ||= Ckeditor::Utils.filethumb(filename)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :data line from your code, or just change the editor .

Comment: I will test it and let you know